# Data Wrangling in python exclude entries with '0' values

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a pandas data frame that contains 2 columns W(number of Wins) and L(number of Losses).
I would like to eliminate all rows of data that have a value of 0 for both W and L.

```
pitching_df.groupby('playerID')['W', 'L'].sum()

playerID    W   L
aardsda01   2   5
aasedo01    3   8
abbotpa01   0   0
abernte02   8   19
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
df[df[['W', 'L']].ne(0).all(1)]


playerID        W   L
0   aardsda01   2   5
1   aasedo01    3   8
3   abernte02   8   19
```

Comment: This solution works.  I understand the .ne(0) means not equal to 0 but what does .all(1) mean?

Comment: Thanks, all(1) ensures columnwise operation.

Comment: BTW, how did you find the blank space in the end ? :)

Answer (score 0):

Some other options:

```
df[~((df.W == 0) & (df.L == 0))]

df.query('not (W == 0 and L == 0)')
```